# How to Share session between different clients accessing a Meteor website? Collaborative ToDos?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, collaboration

I am learning web development and lately Meteor has caught my fancy.

1. I went through the starter tutorial of creating to-dos and use save button to commit the list to database. It allows everybody who opens the website to see the same to-dos list.
2. I added user log in system in to-dos so that people can login and see only their own to-do list.
3. Now, I'm trying to extend above example, for Collaborative to-dos.

    Here is a sample use case:

---

My boss logs-in at do.com and starts creating his to-do list. While the Boss is logged in, I also happen to open do.com from my laptop and I see a message flashing - A session is already open. Do you want to collaborate with Boss? If I say 'Yes', Boss will be notified at his screen to allow me access to his list, and on granting access, I will be able to collaborate with Boss's to-do with both of our changes in the list reflecting on each other's screen but the final save/commit button remains frozen for me (because I came later) and remains active only for Boss. So, when Boss hits the save button, the list is committed to database with his and my changes. 
If Boss chooses to not allow me to contribute, I get to see my own to-do.

---

On the other hand, if I choose NO, I get a fresh start at my to-do list with no bearing on already open sessions elsewhere.

---

The scenario should work other way round too. If I am the one who has an active session at do.com and Boss happens to open his own later, he should get the message whether he wants to collaborate with me and so on.

---

What would be the best way to implement this in Meteor? I came across this [Persistent Session package](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) which could be the solution but I am not able to adapt it to my use-case of allowing/denying another user via message/notification. Appreciate, any help on this. I'm a complete newbie here, pls excuse of any un-necessary verbiage, I wanted to explain my question well.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question may not be well received. Make sure you review [mcve] and [ask] before posting. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: @freespirit think about sockets.

Answer (score 3):

Session is not the right tool for this, you want to use the server db (Collections) to mediate this collaboration.

Given that you created todo lists specific to users, I'm going to assume you have a publication somewhat like this:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
    return Tasks.find({owner: this.userId});
  });
}
```

So the next step is to change this so you can see your own tasks, and also those belonging to any user who shares their tasks with you.  This could be created like this:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
CanView = new Mongo.Collection('canView');

// CanView holds docs with this schema:
//   {
//      user: 'DzxiSdNxEhiHMaoi6',
//      taskLists: ['DzxiSdNxEhiHMaoi6', '7X97ZhPxjX6J4eNWx']
//   }


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('tasks', function () {
    var canView = CanView.findOne({user: this.userId}).taskLists;
    return Tasks.find({owner: {$in: canView}});
  });
}
```

On the client tasks could be displayed as one single list, or segregated by the owner property.

How you add and remove ids into the CanViews tasklist list will depend on the workflow for requesting access/offering to share, etc.

The other part of the workflow you mentioned is only the Boss being able to save the changes, but still have them reactively update on both screens.  This would take more work as you would need to implement a 2 step process,  with two collections on the server. i.e. Boss's (task owner's) saves are committed directly to the canonical `Tasks` collection, and other users saves to a second `TaskUpdates` Collection.  Both published to the clients, which then have to overlay the data from `TaskUpdates` over the actual `Tasks` in a way that is clear and meaningful.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this is so helpful, gives me a point to start.